# Simplify SQL query for me please

Tags: mysql

1. I have a table of multiple employment records of an employee/s where i want to query for a certain range of date.
2. Parameters are Company.id,date_hired,date_end
3. Results must be on the range of the specified date and employee.id must only be one if the employee has multiple employment records result must get the latest employment record..

THIS IS WHAT I CURRENTLY HAVE.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM employmentrecords 
 WHERE employmentrecords.id IN(
    SELECT MAX(employmentrecords.id) 
      FROM employmentrecords 
     WHERE ((employmentrecords.date_end >='2017-08-22' 
        OR employmentrecords.date_end IS NULL 
        OR (employmentrecords.date_end <='2017-08-22' 
        AND employmentrecords.date_end >='2017-08-08')) 
        AND employmentrecords.date_hired <='2017-08-22') 
     GROUP 
        BY employmentrecords.employee_id) 
       AND employmentrecords.company_id<>0`

Hope any one would suggest a better approach.Thank you
```

Comment: What's wrong with it now?

Comment: And what does this have to do with `java`?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: This a question about overlaps, right? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I got your question all clear, this query below will give you the latest employee record if there are multiple user records -

```
SELECT * FROM employmentrecords WHERE id IN(SELECT MAX(id) FROM employmentrecords 
    WHERE ((date_end >='2017-08-22' 
            OR date_end IS NULL 
            OR (date_end <='2017-08-22' AND date_end >='2017-08-08')) 
            AND date_hired <='2017-08-22') 
    GROUP BY employee_id) 
    AND company_id<>0
    and rownum = 1
    order by date_hired desc
```

JFYI, no need to use the table name as alias if there is only one table you are fetching the data from, it just makes it hard to read the query on go.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, max(date_hired)
      FROM employmentrecords 
     WHERE ((employmentrecords.date_end >='2017-08-22' 
        OR employmentrecords.date_end IS NULL 
        OR (employmentrecords.date_end <='2017-08-22' 
        AND employmentrecords.date_end >='2017-08-08')) 
        AND employmentrecords.date_hired <='2017-08-22') group by id
```